# I can authorize user but can't get data from firestore in flutter for web

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore, flutter-web

I am trying to develop admin page for my mobile application but faced with issue like getting data from firestore. I can login without any issue but cant get data. Please check my codes and help me to solve this issue. Thanks in advance

I don't know if it is valid to use stream builder like this in flutter web or is there another way to fetch data

```
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:uni_flensburg_web/services/auth.dart';




class Home extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomeState createState() => _HomeState();
}

class _HomeState extends State<Home> {

  final AuthService _auth = AuthService();
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
            actions: [
              IconButton(icon: Icon(Icons.verified_user),
              onPressed: ()async{
                await _auth.signOut();
              }
              )
            ],
          ),

          body:StreamBuilder(
          stream: Firestore.instance.collection('news').limit(20).snapshots(),
          builder: (context, snapshot) {
            if (!snapshot.hasData) {
              return Center(
                child: CircularProgressIndicator(
                value: null,
                strokeWidth: 2.0,
              ));
            } else {
              return ListView.builder(
                physics: const AlwaysScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                itemCount: snapshot.data.documents.length,
                itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                  DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot =
                      snapshot.data.documents[index];
                  return Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                          right: 18.0,
                          left: 18.0,
                          bottom: 14.0,
                        ),
```

And this is my index.html file

```
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta content="IE=Edge" http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible">
  <meta name="description" content="A new Flutter project.">

  <!-- iOS meta tags & icons -->
  <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
  <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black">
  <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-title" content="uni_flensburg_web">
  <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="icons/Icon-192.png">

  <!-- Favicon -->
  <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png" href="favicon.png"/>

  <title>uni_flensburg_web</title>
  <link rel="manifest" href="manifest.json">
</head>
<body>
  <!-- This script installs service_worker.js to provide PWA functionality to
       application. For more information, see:
       https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/primers/service-workers -->

  <!-- The core Firebase JS SDK is always required and must be listed first -->
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.14.5/firebase-app.js"></script>

<!-- TODO: Add SDKs for Firebase products that you want to use
     https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup#available-libraries -->
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.14.5/firebase-analytics.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.14.6/firebase-auth.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.14.6/firebase-firestore.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.14.5/firebase-storage.js"></script>


<script>
  // Your web app's Firebase configuration
  var firebaseConfig = {
    apiKey: "",
    authDomain: "",
    databaseURL: "",
    projectId: "",
    storageBucket: "",
    messagingSenderId: "",
    appId: "",
    measurementId: ""
  };
  // Initialize Firebase
  firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
  firebase.analytics();
</script>


  <script>
    if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
      window.addEventListener('load', function () {
        navigator.serviceWorker.register('flutter_service_worker.js');
      });
    }
  </script>
  <script src="main.dart.js" type="application/javascript"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

And this is pubspec.yaml

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter


  # The following adds the Cupertino Icons font to your application.
  # Use with the CupertinoIcons class for iOS style icons.
  cupertino_icons: ^0.1.3
  firebase_auth: ^0.16.1
  firebase_core: ^0.4.3
  firebase_auth_web: ^0.1.3+1
  cloud_firestore: ^0.12.9+5
  provider: ^4.1.2
  flutter_spinkit: "^4.1.2"
  flutter_form_builder: 3.8.0+1
```